# Resource Names From Portable Class Library

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, portable-class-library

I'm trying to load BitmapImages from a sportable class library (referenced from a WP8 app). I need tp first check whether the resources are part of the assembly, the fall back to loading them from the application directory if not. This works fine if the images are in the same assembly, but not when they're in a portable class library.

This is the code I'm using to get the names of all resources in the portable class library:

```
public static IEnumerable<object> GetResourcePaths(Assembly assembly) {
    var culture = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
    var mrn = assembly.GetManifestResourceNames();
    // mrn contains all of my image resources
    foreach (var resource in mrn) {
        var rm = new ResourceManager(resource.Replace(".resources", ""), assembly);

        //When I call either of the next two lines, I get a 'System.Resources.MissingManifestResourceException'
        var NOT_USED = rm.GetStream("app.xaml"); // without getting a stream, next statement doesn't work - bug?
        var rs = rm.GetResourceSet(Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture, false, true);

        var enumerator = rs.GetEnumerator();
        while (enumerator.MoveNext()){
            yield return enumerator.Key.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this article about how to access resources from PCL:
http://www.irisclasson.com/2012/11/01/example-windows-store-app-portable-class-library-how-to-access-and-use-pcl-resources/

Note however that this article is about reading text content from PCL, not images. I haven't managed to load bitmaps stored as embedded resource in a PCL from another assembly. It's also discouraged to store in PCLs such platform specific stuff as bitmaps, because the way you handle and even load them is very much platform-specific.

Comment: I'm already loading text resources without a problem, it's the bitmaps which cause problems.

Comment: I see. In a similar situation I eventually gave up and started loading images as content.